# Finding localStorage in FF dev-tools

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How can I see what is in the localStorage such as in Google Chrome: Resources -> Local Storage

(I  mean in FF dev tools, not Firebug)

Answer (score 5):

Firefox has since [added this feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector). To enable it, go into Settings (by clicking the cog icon in Developer Tools),  and tick Storage under the list of Default Firefox Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

We plan to add a storage panel at some point that can be used to inspect all types of local storage. Until then you could use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/foundstone-html5-local-storage/).